# Ratio retained for picture

Tags: visualforce

I have installed the Picture Uploader app, however the picture is always displayed as a square, which means the user has to crop the photo before uploading.

How would i edit the code below so the ratio of the picture is maintained whilst ensuring the width isn't any more than 100px?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-color : #FFFFFF!important;}
    .pic {
        background-color : #FFFFFF;
        border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
        height:100px;
        margin :15px auto;
        padding:5px;
        width:100px;
    }
</style>

<apex:outputpanel styleClass="pic" id="image" layout="block">
     <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PictureUploader, '/images/unknownperson.jpg')}" rendered="{!NOT( hasPicture )}" height="100" width="100"/>
     <apex:image value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!file.Id}" rendered="{!hasPicture}" height="100" width="100"/>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673900/how-to-center-and-crop-an-image-to-square-with-css

Comment: Alex, that sounds like a pure HTML / CSS question. Is there a relation specific to Salesforce ? Ifnot these type of questions are best asked at stackoverflow.com as there are many more html/css experts there.

Comment: This was answered by Bar. It was Salesforce specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `height` and `width` on [apex:image](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_image.htm) is shown below, with the important bit in bold:

> **height:** The height at which this image should be displayed, expressed either as a relative percentage of the total available
>   vertical space (for example, height="50%") or as a number of pixels
>   (for example, height="100px"). **If not specified, this value defaults
>   to the dimension of the source image file**
>
> **width:**
>   The width at which this image is displayed, expressed either as a
>   relative percentage of the total available horizontal space (for
>   example, width="50%") or as a number of pixels (for example,
>   width="100px"). **If not specified, this value defaults to the dimension
>   of the source image file.**

You should be able to simply remove the `height="100"` from the `apex:image` tags to make sure the images are displayed correctly. You also have the height and width set on the `apex:outputpanel` tag so you may have to remove the height from that as well.